# Prove a certain function maps to upper half plane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, operator-theory, differential-operators

Suppose $M$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on space of **complex valued** functions on the real line $S_1=L^2(\mathbb{R},a(x)dx)$, where $a(x)$ is a nice real positive analytical function ( I have in mind a decaying exponential weight). All inner products written below are taken to be on $S_1$.

Also consider the space of **real valued** functions on the real line $S_2=L^2_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R},a(x)dx)$

Let $R(\lambda)=(M-\lambda I)^{-1}$.

It is standard fact that for any $f$ in $S_1$ (and hence, also for any $f$ in $S_2$), we have the

$A(\lambda)=\langle R(\lambda)f,f\rangle$ maps $\lambda$ from upper half plane to upper half plane.

My question is:

1). **SPECIFIC CASE**: Suppose $f$ is taken to be in $S_2$. Then under what conditions can we claim that :

$B(\lambda)=\langle R(\lambda)f,f^3\rangle$ also maps $\lambda$ from  upper half plane to upper half plane.

The motivation is that I find numerically the spectrum of a perturbed operator to be real. If I do a expansion for eigenvalues in terms of the resolvent $R$, I get the term like B. If one can prove B has the desired properties, it can be used to prove the spectrum is real.

2). **GENERAL CASE**: Now suppose we have two functions $g$ in $S_2$ and $f$ in $S_2$.

Under what conditions can we claim that

$C(\lambda)=\langle R(\lambda)f,g\rangle$ also maps $\lambda$ from  upper half plane to upper half plane.

Comment: $f$ belongs to which space?

Comment: $a(x)$ is a positive-valued measurable function? also I imagine that functions are complex-valued?

Comment: sorry, I'm still confused: in $L^2(\mathbf{C},a(x)dx)$ you mean functions on $\mathbf{R}$, and valued in $\mathbf{C}$?

Comment: @YCor Yes, I was using the wrong notation. Fixed it.

Comment: You can write $L^2_\mathbf{K}(A,\mu)$ for $\mathbf{K}$-valued $L^2$-functions on $(A,\mu)$, I think it's standard.